# What does it mean when you pass a for loop into an any function in python?

Tags: python, cs50

I am currently studying [CS50's Introduction to Artificial Intelligence with Python](https://www.edx.org/course/cs50s-introduction-to-artificial-intelligence-with-python). I've encountered a line of code that doesn't make sense to me and I can't seem to find any resources online to explain this to me.

```
def contains_state(self,state):
    return any(node.state == state for node in self.frontier)
```

This is a method in a Python class. What baffles me is how do I make sense of `node.state == state for node in self.frontier`?

My understanding of [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is that it checks if any of the element that is being iterated is True but how does the code above work?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Keyword: "Generator expression", see also "list comprehension".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside any is a generator object with boolean values (either True or False). While going through the for loop, if any `node.state == state`, contains_state returns `True`.

The advantage of using a generator over a list is that you don't have to iterate through every element if you find a node whose state is equal to the state you are looking for. Therefore, in some/most cases it will run faster.

If it goes through the entire loop and none of the nodes' states equals the state passed to `contains_state`, the function returns `False`. You can learn more about generators [here](https://eklitzke.org/generator-comprehensions-and-using-any-and-all-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

`self.frontier` is an iterable.

`node.state == state for node in self.frontier` iterates thru `self.frontier` and creates a new list of True and False values based on if the state matches.

`any(...)` is returning True if any of that list contains True.

It's roughly equivalent to:

```
node_states = []
for node in self.frontier:
    node_states.append(node.state == state)

return any(node_states)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on here:

- **any() function**

> https://beginnersbook.com/2019/03/python-any-function/
>
> Python any() function accepts iterable (list, tuple, dictionary etc.)
> as an argument and return true if any of the element in iterable is
> true, else it returns false. If iterable is empty then any() method
> returns false.

- **Python iterable**

> https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Iterables.html
>
> An iterable is any Python object capable of returning its members one
> at a time, permitting it to be iterated over in a for-loop.

- **function's return value:** `any(node.state == state for node in self.frontier)`

  Returns "true" if any "note.value" in any of the "nodes" in the list "self.frontier" have the same value as input parameter "state".

Answer (score 0):

`node.state == state for node in self.frontier` is a generator with a `__next__` method. When something calls `__next__`, the generator fetches a value from `self.frontier`, compares its `state` variable to  `state` and returns the result. When `self.frontier` raises `StopIteration`, that exception is passed to the caller.

`any()` is the consumer. It calls `__next__` until something is true and returns True. If `__next__` raises `StopIteration`, it returns `False`.

Example

```
>>> state = 'foo'
>>> frontier = ['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> gen = (value == state for value in frontier)
>>> type(gen)
<class 'generator'>
>>> gen.__next__()
False
>>> gen.__next__()
False
>>> gen.__next__()
True
>>> gen.__next__()
False
>>> gen.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> 
>>> any(value == state for value in frontier)
True
```